# Entity Framework "Include" does not load entity related tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a project with ASP.NET Core 3.1 using Visual Studio 2019 (64 bit) and SQL Server 2019. When I run the backend it generates an error when I use Entity Framework's `.Include` to load data from a related table. It's strange that the same code worked with no problem using ASP.NET Core 2.1 in Visual Studio 2017. This happens to me in every method where I use `.Include` to load data from a related table.

The following image shows the error generated when I run the backend:

[image]

This is the method where I use the `.Include`:

```
namespace Sistema.Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ArticulosController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DbContextSistema _context;

        public object Articulos { get; private set; }

        public ArticulosController(DbContextSistema context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<ArticuloViewModel>> Listar()
        {
            var articulo = await _context.Articulos.Include(a=>a.categoria).ToListAsync();
            return articulo.Select(a => new ArticuloViewModel
            {
                idarticulo = a.idarticulo,
                idcategoria = a.idcategoria,
                categoria = a.categoria.nombre,
                codigo = a.codigo,
                nombre = a.nombre,
                stock = a.stock,
                precio_venta = a.precio_venta,
                descripcion = a.descripcion,
                condicion = a.condicion
            });
        }

        private bool ArticuloExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Articulos.Any(e => e.idarticulo == id);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the entity of the main table (Articulo):

```
namespace Sistema.Entidades.Almacen
{
    public class Articulo
    {
        public int idarticulo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int idcategoria { get; set; }
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal precio_venta { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int stock { get; set; }
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public bool condicion { get; set; }

        public Categoria categoria { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the entity of the related table (Categoria):

```
namespace Sistema.Entidades.Almacen
{
    public class Categoria
    {
        public int idcategoria { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        [StringLength(256)]
        public string descripcion { get; set; }
        public bool condicion { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Articulo> articulos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the mapping class for `Articulo`:

```
namespace Sistema.Datos.Mapping.Almacen
{
    public class ArticuloMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Articulo>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Articulo> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("articulo")
                .HasKey(a => a.idarticulo);     
        }
    }
}
```

This is the mapping class for `Categoria`:

```
namespace Sistema.Datos.Mapping.Almacen
{
    public class CategoriaMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Categoria>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Categoria> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("categoria")
                .HasKey(c => c.idcategoria);
            builder.Property(c => c.nombre)
                .HasMaxLength(50);
            builder.Property(c => c.descripcion)
                .HasMaxLength(256);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `DbContext` where I include my `ArticuloMap` and `CategoriaMap`:

```
namespace Sistema.Datos
{
    public class DbContextSistema : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Articulo> Articulos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Rol> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Persona> Personas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ingreso> Ingresos { get; set; }

        public object Entry(object articulos)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public DbSet<DetalleIngreso> DetalleIngresos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Venta> Ventas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DetalleVenta> DetalleVentas { get; set; }

        public DbContextSistema(DbContextOptions<DbContextSistema> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CategoriaMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ArticuloMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RolMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UsuarioMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PersonaMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new IngresoMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DetalleIngresoMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new VentaMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DetalleVentaMap());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the db table design for `articulo` and `categoria` and the db relationships as requested:

[image]

Has something changed in .NET Core 3.1? Is there something I need to change or adjust to fix this issue? Thank you very much in advance for your responses!

**EDIT:**

- Replaced images for source code.
- Added source code of the entity of the related table `Categoria`.
- Added source code of the mapping class `CategoriaMap`.
- Added an image of the db table design and relationships.

I apologize in advance for making the post only with images instead of the source code. Thank you for your responses, I hope that the last Edit make things more clear for a solution to the problem.

Comment: please include code **as text, not as screenshot**. and use the preview function to check for proper formatting.

Comment: Given that it's harder to take a screenshot and add to a question than just paste code, I always wondered why people take the hard route..

Comment: What is the name of the db column in Articulo that Is the foreign key to categoria.id? If it's `idcategoria` I believe you'll have to tell EF this via the mapping config because by convention it would expect it to be CategoriaId - the way English speakers say it. I can't quite believe this worked by convention before; your old code probably had a mapping that you've forgotten you created

Comment: The way it is shown, no way this could work in *any* EF (Core) version.  Intended FK property name `idcategoria` does not match FK name conventions for nav property name `categoria`, so it needs manual configuration - either fluently or data annotation.

Comment: TLDR; you need to show us your db table design and relationships before we can help you

Comment: @CaiusJard I've just updated the post and added the db table design and relations. To answer your question, the foreign key name for the column is `idcategoria`. The reason I am not doing it by convention is because I'm working with the project in Spanish. I used the same code on another computer with Visual Studio 2017 using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and it didn't show the previous issue shown above.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten this footnote: *Note: Before EF Core 3.0 the property named exactly the same as the principal key property was also matched as the foreign key*

Comment: Most simply, I suppose you'll need to annotate either `articulos` or `categoria` property with `[ForeignKey("idcategoria")]` to let EF know that articulo.idcategoria is the column that links articulo to categoria

Comment: @CaiusJard If that's the case, it would make a lot of sense since it worked perfectly in EF Core 2.1. Where would I need to make the annotation? In the Controller or in the mapping's code? Could you send an example of how it would be done? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to tell EF how to wire up a relationship. By default for your objects:

```
//principal
public class Categoria
{
    public int idcategoria { get; set; }

    ...

    public ICollection<Articulo> articulos { get; set; }
}

//dependent
public class Articulo
{
    public int idarticulo { get; set; }
    public int idcategoria { get; set; }

    ...

    public Categoria categoria { get; set; }
}
```

EF will be able to see these are related, because an Articulo has a Categoria and a Categoria has many Articulo so it can infer how the 1:M relationship is structured. When guessing which column of the dependent links to the principal it tries:

- *categoria*idcategoria (italics -> dependent navigation property name)
- *categoria*Id
- *Categoria*idcategoria (italics -> principal class name)
- *Categoria*Id

Most critically it no longer (since 3.0) tries to find a pair of properties between the two classes that have identical names, which I presume was why it worked before

---

If your naming convention was typical English it'd have found it, but with those rules it won't find a Spanish style name so you'll have to be explicit, probably easiest by annotating either of the properties in the relationship (EF doesn't care which) - I see arguments for either way being acceptable:

- If you do it in the dependent, then you're referencing a property in the same class so you don't have to look in another class/open another file to check what it's referring to
- If you do it in the principal, then you're describing how a property of *this* class links to what property of *that* class

So it looks like:

```
//principal
public class Categoria
{
    public int idcategoria { get; set; }

    ...

    [ForeignKey("idcategoria")] //it means Articulo.idcategoria is the relevant property that links to PK of this class
    public ICollection<Articulo> articulos { get; set; }
}
```

OR

```
//dependent
public class Articulo
{
    public int idarticulo { get; set; }
    public int idcategoria { get; set; }

    ...

    [ForeignKey("idcategoria")] //it means idcategoria proerty above is the relevant property that links to PK property of Categoria
    public Categoria categoria { get; set; }
}
```

I guess just pick whichever you like more and be consistent. The examples in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=data-annotations%2Cdata-annotations-simple-key%2Csimple-key) use dependent

Comment: It works perfectly! I didn't know that EF changed the convention for the table relations after 3.0, now I understand much better how to specify the foreign keys in the related table, also thanks for linking the documentation, it helps a lot. Thank you very much!